# Sql Server 2008 >> msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

Can anyone please tell me the name of Master table used by sqlserver 2008 to store dbmail information?

I tried to truncate "sysmail_sentitems" table but it gives me foreign key constraint violation error. Please reply if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to truncate `sysmail_sentitems` which is a view, I doubt that possible.

Master table used by sqlserver 2008 to store dbmail information is `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems`.

I navigate through `SP_Helptext sysmail_sentitems` which give another view `sysmail_allitems`. Using SP_Helptext sysmail_allitems gives me a table `sysmail_mailitems`.

I think `sysmail_mailitems` is the table which you need.